# Get event duration for a specific time period per user

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

This is an example of my table. I have multiple entries on multiple rows for a given `post_id` (this is metadata for posts).

```
post_id | meta_key       | meta_value
________ ________________ ____________________
        |                |
1       | _theDate       | 2016-03-31 12:03:59
1       | _email         | the@email.com
1       | _EventDuration | 32400
2       | _theDate       | 2016-01-06 14:50:22
2       | _email         | the@email.com
2       | _EventDuration | 32400
3       | _theDate       | 2017-02-14 15:32:52
3       | _email         | other@user.net
3       | _EventDuration | 32400
4       | _theDate       | 2016-10-01 22:45:55
4       | _email         | the@email.com
4       | _EventDuration | 32400
5       | _theDate       | 2016-09-25 11:01:39
5       | _email         | other@user.net
5       | _EventDuration | 32400
6       | _theDate       | 2015-11-19 19:08:45
6       | _email         | other@user.net
6       | _EventDuration | 32400
```

What I am trying to accomplish:

I would like to get these results from the database to make a table displaying the number of hours (`_EventDuration`) worked for each user (`_email`) each month (using `_theDate` for example, `2015-11`) for each event (`post_id`). I can do this using PHP variables on my end.

So I can then make HTML tables to show this information in the following way **(I'm *not* looking for an answer for this part like converting seconds to hours, it's purely just so you know what I want to accomplish with all the data from the table):**

```
Hours the@email.com worked in 2015-11
Date            Hours
2015-11-01      9
2015-11-13      7
2015-11-27      5
2015-11-30      8

Hours the@email.com worked in 2015-12
Date            Hours
2015-12-01      10
2015-12-13      7
2015-12-27      3
2015-12-30      6
```

All I have for the moment is this request to count the number of events a user has done in 2017 for example :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT post_id 
         FROM metatable 
        WHERE (meta_key = '_email' AND meta_value LIKE '%$user_email%')                 
           OR (meta_key = '_theDate' AND LEFT(meta_value, 4) LIKE '%2017%') 
        GROUP 
           BY post_id 
       HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT meta_key) = 2
     ) p
```

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Yes, I have this request to count the number of events a user has done in 2017 for example : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT post_id FROM  `metatable` WHERE (meta_key = '_email' AND meta_value LIKE '%$user_email%') OR (meta_key = '_theDate' AND LEFT(meta_value, 4) LIKE '%2017%') GROUP BY post_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT meta_key) = 2) p

Comment: Put the code in the question, comments are not readable.

Comment: Can you edit your post and write down this query and one thing please, why there is this p in the last of the query ?

Comment: Why not to create separate columns for meta keys?

Comment: @Alex78191 This is the way to normalize a general metadata table so you can have arbitrary keys.

Comment: It's common in frameworks like WordPress, because they can't predict what kind of attributes you'll need.

Comment: @Barmar What NF?

Comment: OK, maybe normalization is the wrong name for this. The point is that you don't want to hard-code all the possible keys into column names when you're designing a general-purpose data store.

Comment: I want to get per user : the dates of each event and the `_EventDuration` value (which I can convert to hours later).

Comment: @PatrickMacCann it's WP?

Comment: If it was me, and I was obliged to use an EAV model, I'd separate the attributes out into discrete tables based on data type. Just sayin'

Comment: @Alex78191 Yes it's Wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery to pivot the table to get email, date, and Hours into different columns for each post. Then you can use a normal grouped query to get the total per day and user.

```
SELECT Email, Date, SUM(Hours) AS Hours
FROM (
    SELECT MAX(IF(meta_key = '_email', meta_value, NULL)) AS Email,
           MAX(IF(meta_key = '_theDate', DATE(meta_value), NULL)) AS Date, 
           SUM(IF(meta_key = '_EventDuration', meta_value, 0))/3600 AS Hours
    FROM metatable
    GROUP BY post_id
) AS x
GROUP BY Email, Date
ORDER BY Email, Date
```

Comment: Sorry, someone renamed my question and that's not what I want to find. I want to get per user : the dates of each event and the `_EventDuration` value (which I can convert to hours later).

Comment: This looks like a great start. So then I can get the results using PHP and search the array for the user's email address I guess and find the related info? Please correct me if I'm wrong. I'm kind of new to this! PS : This is on Wordpress

Comment: You can use `IF(meta_key = '_email' AND meta_value = 'the@email.com`, meta_value, NULL))` to match a specific email instead of returning them all.

Comment: It's just a way to ignore all the `NULL` values from the rows that don't match the `IF` criteria. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table